# Call out of Webapp does crash iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, web-applications, fullscreen

I currently build an in-house webapp (a telephone directory) with jQuery Mobile. I put the phone numbers in a link: `<a href="tel:000">call me </a>`

This works great. Once you hang up, you get back to the home screen (normal behavior for webapps). BUT: If you start the phone app, the iPhone crashes. The phone app does not open, the status bar will light up and everything is slowly increased. Sometimes the screen goes black and you must restart the iPhone. Workaround: double-clicking the homebutton and chose another multitask app. Then again, everything is normal.

After thousands of attempts, I've come to the conclusion that the problem appears ONLY on the fullscreen mode:

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
```

Leaving this off and opens the webapp with the Safari interface: no problems.

I've Been looking into the vastness of the internet for the problem, but somehow I seem to be the only one ...?
We tested on an iPhone 4 and an iPhone 4S. Both with the latest iOS version.

You can also try it out: [www.gopeter.de/tel](http://www.gopeter.de/tel) - put the app to your homescreen/springboard, phone 0000 and hang up immediately. Thereafter, the normal "phone" app stop working ...

Source code of this page is only:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />    
    <title>Anrufen</title>
</head>
<body>
     <a href="tel:0000">call me</a>
</body>
</html>
```